# i used ionic-img-viewer for viewing image but it raised Cannot find module "rxjs/operators" error

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic-native

i tried to use Programmatic ionic-img-viewer throw error:Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "rxjs/operators"
My app.module.ts:

```
 import { IonicImageViewerModule } from 'ionic-img-viewer';
     ...
   imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AllTrainSortPipe,
        DepartureSortPipe,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
        HttpModule,
        IonicImageViewerModule
    ]
```

home.ts:

```
        import { ImageViewerController } from 'ionic-img-viewer';
        ...

    export class StationPage{
    private _imageViewerCtrl: ImageViewerController;

         constructor(imageViewerCtrl: ImageViewerController)
        {
         this._imageViewerCtrl = imageViewerCtrl; 
         }

          presentImage(myImage) {
                const imageViewer = this._imageViewerCtrl.create(myImage);
                imageViewer.present();
            }
    }
```

Comment: which version are you using and also which version of rxjs is installed?

Comment: angular version:4.4.3                                                                              rxjs: "5.4.3",

Comment: no.. the `ionic-img-viewer` version and `rxjs` version

Comment: ionic-img-viewer:2.9.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `ionic-img-viewer` was updated to use [lettable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md) of rxjs [5.5.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#550-beta0-2017-09-22) in version [2.9.0](https://github.com/Riron/ionic-img-viewer/commit/4ae796e13dcd00ed581e5fbe9d643f45b67b2d26).

Your option is to update rxjs version to the current 5.5.2.

```
npm i rxjs@5.5.2 --save
```

This may include updating your code to use lettable operators or install an older version of `ionic-img-viewer`.

```
npm i ionic-img-viewer@2.8.0 --save
```

Comment: `npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: ion-img-viewer@2.8.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/users/username/.npm/_logs/2017-11-28T13_08_22_054Z-debug.log
` error

Comment: try `npm view ionic-img-viewer versions`

Comment: also it is `ionic-img-viewer@2.8.0` @sam